# creating new column within multiindex

Tags: pandas

I have a simple dataframe:

```
     A       B
     1   2   1   2
Foo  100 200 300 400
Bar  100 200 300 400
```

I want to add a new column which is (B,2) - (A,2)

What I've tried is:
df["Chg","Period"] = [df.loc[:, [("B",2)]] - df.loc[:, [("A", 2)]]]

But I'm told that:

Length of values does not match length of index

I'm a bit confused - I thought that by having two column headers for my new column it would work, but I'm now struggling. Any help would be most appreciated

Thanks

Comment: @anky `[[...]]` or `[(...)]`?

Comment: ahh misread the ques @QuangHoang OP needs a subtraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tuples for select `MultiIndex` and also for new MultiIndex column:

```
df[("Chg","Period")]  = df[("B",2)] - df[("A", 2)]

print (df)
       A         B         Chg
       1    2    1    2 Period
Foo  100  200  300  400    200
Bar  100  200  300  400    200
```

If want working by multiple columns together, e.g. subtract `B` with `A` to new MultiIndex levels is possible use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), then create MultiIndex by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and add to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df.xs('B', axis=1, level=0) - df.xs('A', axis=1, level=0)
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Diff'], df1.columns])
print (df1)
    Diff     
       1    2
Foo  200  200
Bar  200  200

df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
       A         B      Diff     
       1    2    1    2    1    2
Foo  100  200  300  400  200  200
Bar  100  200  300  400  200  200
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. I was going round in circles!